# Why does a unquoted wildcard work remotely with scp?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I'm typing this in Bash:

```
scp user@remote:~/dir/*.xml .
```

and it works, getting all the files that make the wildcard on the remote server. But why does this work? I thought that Bash expands wildcard expressions in arguments before the arguments become visible to a tool like `scp`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If there is no matching filename, then a wildcard expression in bash expands to itself. So, as long as you don't create any file locally whose name matches `user@remote:~/dir/*.xml`, your command works without quoting.

Comment: And also don't enable `nullglob` which would have it expand to empty string

Comment: `nullglob` doesn't cause the pattern to expand to the empty string; it causes it to disappear altogether. It's the difference between `scp "" .` (two arguments, one of which is the empty string) and `scp .` (a single argument and an invalid call to `scp`).